# How do I connect 16 SATA-drives to one Adaptec ASR-6805 KIT? (2 SFF-8087 Internal Ports)

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

Kit includes only 2 cords SFF-8087 to 4xSATA... Sum is 8. I need 16. What should I do? No way to change the controller. But can buy additional cards or wires if needed. Please advise.

Comment: Just as a word of warning, Adaptec RAID cards are junk.  Return it and get one that won't bite you in the ass - LSI's yet to let me down.

Comment: Why LSI is better?

Comment: I don't honestly know *why* LSI is better, I just know that everyone I've ever met who's used an Adaptec RAID controller has had it crap out on them, whereas LSI is what both Dell and HP use in their servers.  LSI just works, Adpatec just doesn't.

Comment: Well, anyway thank your for the info. Will try to compare LSI against Adaptec & try to get more reviews from the guys who used them.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of direct-attached disk drives is 8. You can use up to 256 with expanders. (pg.32) The topology and options for SAS Expanders is described on pg. 76.

[Adaptec Raid Controller - Installation And User's Guide 3/2014](http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/adaptec_raid_controller_iug_3_2014.pdf)